# How to Start page numbering on page 9? office 2007

Tags: microsoft-office

Can I somehow appear in footer the page numbering only from the ninth page?
I do not want to appear the page numbers on the first 8 pages.

Answer (score 3):

Create a section break at the end of page 8. Insert a footer on page 9, then turn off **Link to Previous** in the ribbon. Then you can edit the footer on page 9 independent of the footers on the previous pages.